# How to find out line-endings in a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, newline, line-endings

I'm trying to use something in bash to show me the line endings in a file printed rather than interpreted. The file is a dump from SSIS/SQL Server being read in by a Linux machine for processing.

- Are there any switches within `vi`, `less`, `more`, etc?
- In addition to seeing the line-endings, I need to know what type of line end it is (`CRLF` or `LF`). How do I find that out?

Comment: General tip: If you have an idea of which *nix/cygwin command you might use, you can always view its manpage to search for switches that might give you the functionality you need. E.g., `man less`.

Answer (score 590, accepted):

You can use the `file` utility to give you an indication of the type of line endings.

Unix:

```
$ file testfile1.txt
testfile.txt: ASCII text
```

"DOS":

```
$ file testfile2.txt
testfile2.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

To convert from "DOS" to Unix:

```
$ dos2unix testfile2.txt
```

To convert from Unix to "DOS":

```
$ unix2dos testfile1.txt
```

Converting an already converted file has no effect so it's safe to run blindly (i.e. without testing the format first) although the usual disclaimers apply, as always.

Comment: These are now sometimes named "fromdos" and "todos", respectively (as is the case in Ubuntu 10.4+)

Comment: @JessChadwick: Yes, but only if you explicitly install the `tofrodos` package with `sudo apt-get install tofrodos` - just as you'd have to run `sudo apt-get install dos2unix` to get `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`.

Comment: Actully dos2unix can't do all the work,  I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828554/dos2unix-doesnt-convert-m gives best answer

Comment: @nathan: What does `dos2unix` fail at? The OP at that question only vaguely describes the issue.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson   file command before and after dos2unix command got same output: xxx.c C source, ASCII text, with CR, LF line terminators.  I found  this c file has  ^M   in the middle of line which likes xxxxxxx   ^M xxxxxxx

Comment: Just to chime in, on debian jessie you may need to install the `file` package to have `file` command in the first place.

Comment: This won't work for files like ssh keys, which are nonetheless ASCII (use `file -bi` to verify that) since `file` will name them aptly, and won't show information about line endings; also, the OP asked for line endings to be printed, not just what type they are (LF or CRLF), so the answer by @Alex Shelemin is more appropriate.

Comment: This won't work for json files: `file testfile1.json`. Output: `JSON data`. In that case I had to use: file  `testfile1.json --exclude json`. I think `file -k` is the correct command.

Answer (score 313):

Ubuntu 14.04:

simple `cat -e <filename>` works just fine.

This displays Unix line endings (`\n` or LF) as `$` and Windows line endings (`\r\n` or CRLF) as `^M$`.

Comment: Also works on OSX. Good solution. Simple and worked for me while the accepted answer did not. (Note: was not a `.txt` file)

Comment: is the display of M$ an easteregg/windows bashing?

Comment: Does not work with Solaris, but man says tthat it should have worked

Comment: @TomM no. The caret in `^M$` inverts this into an easter egg for Microsoft cultists.

Comment: I find that I have to use `cat -vE <filename>` to see the `\r` characters (displayed as `^M`) and the `\n` characters (displayed as a `$`). This is using GNU `cat` on Linux.

Comment: `cat -e` to show line endings works on `debian 10 buster` with `wsl`

Comment: This actually works but I prefer the `file testfile.txt` answer that does not write all the file, easier to check on several files, for instance I had a script among others that has DOS/Windows ending and was not executed properly, I then simply checked all others to see if they have issue with `file $(find . -name *.sh)`.

Comment: This is very usefull , I had a file with CRLF (copied from windows to a Docker container unix) and unix did not recognise it
The error was "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 147):

In `vi`...

`:set list` to see line-endings.

`:set nolist` to go back to normal.

While I don't think you can see `\n` or `\r\n` in `vi`, you can see which type of file it is (UNIX, DOS, etc.) to infer which line endings it has...

`:set ff`

Alternatively, from `bash` you can use `od -t c <filename>` or just `od -c <filename>` to display the returns.

Comment: Thank you - this has indeed worked - now I'm trying to tell if it's a \n or \r\n is there an additional switch for that in Vi?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think vi can show those specific characters. You can try od -c <filename> which I believe will display \n or \r\n.

Comment: In the "for what it's worth" category you can grep for Dos style CRLF by issuing grep --regex="^M" where ^M is CTRL+V CTRL+M. You can remove those by replacing those with a sed command. This does essentially the same thing as dos2unix

Comment: In vim: `:set fileformat` will report which of `unix` or `dos` vim thinks the file's line endings are in. You can change it by `:set fileformat=unix`.

Comment: Use the -b flag when starting vi/vim and then use :set list to see CR (^M) and LF ($) endings.

Comment: @RyanBerger - Looks like you're missing a -t. It should be `od -t c file/path`, but thanks for the new program. Worked great!

Comment: @RyanBerger you should edit the answer to include "od -c". First thing I've come across that just simply showed the returns. Thank you.

Comment: The utility command `od` should be the correct answer to this ticket.

Comment: Note that the fileformat inferred by Vim (and reported by `:set fileformat`) prefers towards reporting `unix` i.e. it reports `dos` only if every line in the file has CRLF as its line ending, otherwise it reports it as a `unix` format file. If you think the file might be one of those mixed line-ending abominations, vim can't tell you which lines have `\n` and which have `\r\n`.

Comment: To add from @Samuel's comment, using `:set list` might be sufficient to find out line endings. See `:help binary`, option `-b` only changes a few options.

Answer (score 118):

In the bash shell, try `cat -v <filename>`.  This should display carriage-returns for windows files.

(This worked for me in rxvt via Cygwin on Windows XP).

<sup>Editor's note: `cat -v` visualizes `\r` (CR) chars. as `^M`. Thus, line-ending `\r\n` sequences will display as `^M` at the end of each output line. `cat -e` will additionally visualize `\n`, namely as `$`. (`cat -et` will additionally visualize tab chars. as `^I`.)</sup>

Comment: @ChrisK: Try `echo -e 'abc\ndef\r\n' | cat -v` and you should see a `^M` after the "def".

Comment: I wanted to see if the file has ^M(Windows/DOS EOL) and only cat -v showed me that. +1 for that

Comment: ^M = DOS/Windows style

Comment: correction: Thus, line-ending \r\n sequences will display as ^M$

Answer (score 51):

## Try `file`, then `file -k`, then `dos2unix -ih`

`file` will usually be enough. But for tough cases try `file -k` or `dos2unix -ih`.

Details below.

---

### Try `file -k`

**Short version:** `file -k somefile.txt` will tell you line terminators:

- It will output `with CRLF line terminators` for DOS/Windows line terminators.
- It will output `with CR line terminators` for MAC line terminators.
- It will just output `text` for Linux/Unix "LF" line terminators. (So if it does not explicitly mention any kind of `line terminators` then this means: *"LF line terminators"*.)

And for extra weird cases: When you have mixed line terminators:

- `$ echo -ne '1\n2\r\n3\r' | file -k -`
  `/dev/stdin: ASCII text, with CRLF, CR, LF line terminators`

**Long version** see below.

---

### Real world example: Certificate Encoding

I sometimes have to check this for PEM certificate files.

The trouble with regular `file` is this: Sometimes it's trying to be too smart/too specific.

Let's try a little quiz: I've got some files. And one of these files has different line terminators. Which one?

*(By the way: this is what one of my typical "certificate work" directories looks like.)*

Let's try regular `file`:

```
$ file -- *
0.example.end.cer:         PEM certificate
0.example.end.key:         PEM RSA private key
1.example.int.cer:         PEM certificate
2.example.root.cer:        PEM certificate
example.opensslconfig.ini: ASCII text
example.req:               PEM certificate request
```

Huh. It's not telling me the line terminators. And I already *knew* that those were cert files. I didn't need "file" to tell me that.

Some network appliances are really, really picky about how their certificate files are encoded. That's why I need to know.

What else can you try?

You might try `dos2unix` with the `--info` switch like this:

```
$ dos2unix --info -- *
  37       0       0  no_bom    text    0.example.end.cer
   0      27       0  no_bom    text    0.example.end.key
   0      28       0  no_bom    text    1.example.int.cer
   0      25       0  no_bom    text    2.example.root.cer
   0      35       0  no_bom    text    example.opensslconfig.ini
   0      19       0  no_bom    text    example.req
```

So that tells you that: yup, "0.example.end.cer" must be the odd man out. But what kind of line terminators are there? Do *you* know the dos2unix output format by heart? (I don't.)

But fortunately there's the `--keep-going` (or `-k` for short) option in `file`:

```
$ file --keep-going -- *
0.example.end.cer:         PEM certificate\012- , ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators\012- data
0.example.end.key:         PEM RSA private key\012- , ASCII text\012- data
1.example.int.cer:         PEM certificate\012- , ASCII text\012- data
2.example.root.cer:        PEM certificate\012- , ASCII text\012- data
example.opensslconfig.ini: ASCII text\012- data
example.req:               PEM certificate request\012- , ASCII text\012- data
```

Excellent! Now we know that our odd file has DOS (`CRLF`) line terminators. (And the other files have Unix (`LF`) line terminators. This is not explicit in this output. It's implicit. It's just the way `file` expects a "regular" text file to be.)

*(If you wanna share my mnemonic: "L" is for "Linux" and for "LF".)*

Now let's convert the culprit and try again:

```
$ dos2unix -- 0.example.end.cer

$ file --keep-going -- *
0.example.end.cer:         PEM certificate\012- , ASCII text\012- data
0.example.end.key:         PEM RSA private key\012- , ASCII text\012- data
1.example.int.cer:         PEM certificate\012- , ASCII text\012- data
2.example.root.cer:        PEM certificate\012- , ASCII text\012- data
example.opensslconfig.ini: ASCII text\012- data
example.req:               PEM certificate request\012- , ASCII text\012- data
```

Good. Now all certs have Unix line terminators.

### Try `dos2unix -ih`

I didn't know this when I was writing the example above but:

Actually it turns out that dos2unix will give you a header line if you use `-ih` (short for `--info=h`) like so:

```bash
$ dos2unix -ih -- *
 DOS    UNIX     MAC  BOM       TXTBIN  FILE
   0      37       0  no_bom    text    0.example.end.cer
   0      27       0  no_bom    text    0.example.end.key
   0      28       0  no_bom    text    1.example.int.cer
   0      25       0  no_bom    text    2.example.root.cer
   0      35       0  no_bom    text    example.opensslconfig.ini
   0      19       0  no_bom    text    example.req
```

And another "actually" moment: The header format is really easy to remember: Here's two mnemonics:

1. It's DUMB (left to right: d for Dos, u for Unix, m for Mac, b for BOM).
2. And also: "DUM" is just the alphabetical ordering of D, U and M.

#### Further reading

- [`man file`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=file&manpath=CentOS+7.1)
- [`man dos2unix`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dos2unix&manpath=CentOS+7.1)
- Wikipedia: [*Newline*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: It generates output like: `Accounts.java: Java source, ASCII text\012-` on Windows in MinTTY

Comment: @standalone: interesting. I've read weird things about an option called "igncr" -- and what you're saying sounds like that. But can't reproduce what you describe. (I tried inside the Bash inside mintty that comes with Git-for-Windows, "git version 2.24.0.windows.1".)

Comment: Hm, I tried `file -k Accounts.java` inside the mintty that comes with git-for-windows too, but my version is `git version 2.21.0.windows.1`

Comment: Working solution for me is `cat -e file_to_test`

Comment: Thank you for `file -k`, that's exactly what I've been looking for.  The help description of "don't stop at the first match" didn't click for me, but makes sense.

Answer (score 22):

To show CR as `^M` in less use `less -u` or type <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> once less is open.

`man less` says:

> ```
> -u or --underline-special
>
>       Causes backspaces and carriage returns to be treated  as  print-
>       able  characters;  that  is,  they are sent to the terminal when
>       they appear in the input.
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `xxd` to show a hex dump of the file, and hunt through for "0d0a" or "0a" chars.

You can use `cat -v <filename>` as @warriorpostman suggests.

Comment: It works for me with cat v 8.23. Unix line endings will not print any extra info, but DOS line endings will print a "^M".

Comment: That must be what I'm running into with 8.21, given the fact that I'm using unix line endings.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the command `todos filename` to convert to DOS endings, and `fromdos filename` to convert to UNIX line endings. To install the package on Ubuntu, type `sudo apt-get install tofrodos`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `vim -b filename` to edit a file in binary mode, which will show ^M characters for carriage return and a new line is indicative of LF being present, indicating Windows CRLF line endings.  By LF I mean `\n` and by CR I mean `\r`. Note that when you use the -b option the file will always be edited in UNIX mode by default as indicated by `[unix]` in the status line, meaning that if you add new lines they will end with LF, not CRLF.  If you use normal vim without -b on a file with CRLF line endings, you should see `[dos]` shown in the status line and inserted lines will have CRLF as end of line.  The vim documentation for `fileformats` setting explains the complexities.

Also, I don't have enough points to comment on the Notepad++ answer, but if you use Notepad++ on Windows, use the View / Show Symbol / Show End of Line menu to display CR and LF.  In this case LF is shown whereas for vim the LF is indicated by a new line.

Answer (score 1):

I dump my output to a text file. I then open it in notepad ++ then click the show all characters button. Not very elegant but it works.

Comment: This question is tagged as Linux and I don't think notepad++ is for linux.  This should work for windows though.

Answer (score 0):

### Vim - always show Windows newlines as `^M`

If you prefer to always see the Windows newlines in vim render as `^M`, you can add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
set ffs=unix
```

This will make vim interpret every file you open as a unix file. Since unix files have `\n` as the newline character, a windows file with a newline character of `\r\n` will still render properly (thanks to the `\n`) but will have `^M` at the end of the file (which is how vim renders the `\r` character).

---

### Vim - sometimes show Windows newlines

If you'd prefer just to set it on a per-file basis, you can use `:e ++ff=unix` when editing a given file.

---

### Vim - always show filetype (`unix` vs `dos`)

If you want the bottom line of vim to always display what filetype you're editing (and you didn't force set the filetype to unix) you can add to your `statusline` with
`set statusline+=\ %{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&encoding}`.

My full statusline is provided below. Just add it to your `.vimrc`.

```
" Make statusline stay, otherwise alerts will hide it
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%#PmenuSel#
set statusline+=%#LineNr#
" This says 'show filename and parent dir'
set statusline+=%{expand('%:p:h:t')}/%t
" This says 'show filename as would be read from the cwd'
" set statusline+=\ %f
set statusline+=%m\
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%#CursorColumn#
set statusline+=\ %y
set statusline+=\ %{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&encoding}
set statusline+=\[%{&fileformat}\]
set statusline+=\ %p%%
set statusline+=\ %l:%c
set statusline+=\
```

It'll render like

```
.vim/vimrc\                                    [vim] utf-8[unix] 77% 315:6
```

at the bottom of your file

---

### Vim - sometimes show filetype (`unix` vs `dos`)

If you just want to see what type of file you have, you can use `:set fileformat` (this will not work if you've force set the filetype). It will return `unix` for unix files and `dos` for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

More portable, maybe even POSIX.

Given the example above

```
$ printf "abc\ndef\r\n"
abc
def
```

Use `sed`

```
$ printf "abc\ndef\r\n" | sed -n l
abc$
def\r$
```

Use `od`

```
$ printf "abc\ndef\r\n" | od -c  ## optional "-t a"
0000000   a   b   c  \n   d   e   f  \r  \n
0000011
```