# Can't get new line to work using echo in bash script

Tags: html, bash, variables, echo, newline

This is driving me nuts.

```
nl=$"\n"

message="bla bla $some_var such $another_var ${nl} wow $another_var"
echo -e "$message" > file.txt
```

Just prints:

```
bla bla some_var such another_var wow another_var
```

I want it to print:

```
bla bla some_var such another_var
wow another_var
```

SOLUTION: don't use `\n` when outputting to html file use `<br/>` instead LOL

Comment: Aside from the missing closing quote in the variable assignment, the above code should work well.

Comment: Oh yeah fixed. I'll edit the first post to show my actual script.

Comment: echo tends to differ a bit depending on version/shell. show echo --version. You can also switch to printf which should work regardless.

Comment: Using printf it just prints everything on one line also. `printf  "Starbound server status:${nl}${nl}$online ${nl} It is using $real_cpu CPU and $real_memory MB out of 16GB of memory." > status.htm`. How do I `echo --version` without printing `--version`? :(

Comment: Doing `printf "Cake \n pie" > file.txt` doesn't even work.

Comment: You can do /full/path/echo --version (generally /bin/echo). That said if printf "Cake \n pie" > file.txt doesn't work, my guess is your're using some bizarre text editor to read the file. Try it without re-directing the output.

Comment: It works without outputting to a file! But I need to output it to a file.

Comment: @user3079979 What text editor are you using to read the file? Try `cat`, `gedit`, or `vi`

Comment: `msg="nice test\ntoday3"; echo -e "$msg" > test.txt` works for me

Comment: What are you opening the file in? Since \n is unix newline it will not display correctly in DOS editors such as Notepad.

Comment: I'm using nano, why would using a different text editor matter? gedit reports "cannot open display" cat just prints whats inside the bash script file without any editing and I don't understand vi. I don't get why this has to be so hard :/

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/view-line-endings-in-a-text-file

Comment: @RedX That works for me too. I don't get it what's the difference?! I added the `;` to the end but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Ok I guess it has to be the text editor I'm using? I guess I will figure out how to use vi

Comment: `the_nl=$'\n';msg="nice test${the_nl}today5"; echo -e "$msg" > test.txt; cat test.txt` this also works for me

Comment: The thing with the text editor is, if you were using notepad.exe for some reason you would not see a line break as it needs '\r\n' and not only a '\n'. But gedit should work with all kinds of line breaks without a problem. If you `cat` the output you should also see a line break if its in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment on your original question makes me believe you are printing HTML to a file. How are you checking whether it has newlines? If you want to get actual newlines on your website, you should use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

`$"bla"` is used for translations using the current locale in bash.  What you want is the `$'bla'` notation which knows of these backslash escapes.