# dos2unix doesn't convert ^M

Tags: vim, dos2unix

I exported results in a text file from a program running on Windows 7, and copied the file on Xubuntu 14.04. In a terminal, I ran `dos2unix file.txt`, which tells me `converting file out_mapqtl.txt to Unix format`. However, when I look at the file with `less`, I still see the Windows end-of-line as ^M, and `wc -l` returns me "0".

I tried several things described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613834/597069), but none works. I then opened the file in Vim and did `:%s/\r/\r/g` as explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1203971/597069), which worked fine. So any idea why dos2unix didn't work? Would there be a way to avoid opening Vim every time?

Comment: A bit late here... But I wrote a small program that makes life easier than dos2unix when you're not sure about the input format, or when input formats are intermingled : https://github.com/mdolidon/endlines

Comment: @MathiasDolidon Thank you, Mathias!

Comment: Your question can be rephrased as:
Why _doesn't_ dos2unix modify a _text_ file?
~ * ~
Here is a question asking the opposite:
[Why _does_ dos2unix modify a _binary_ file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34257924)
~ * ~
A simple answer to both questions is:
**because dos2unix isn't foolproof**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\r` denotes a carriage return, and on MAC it is used without `\n` to denote a line break. Are you sure the file is in DOS (`\r\n`) format and not MAC (`\r`)?

If VIM really turns out to be the only thing that'll repair your files, you can also invoke it as:

`vim somefile.txt +"%s/\r/\r/g" +wq`

This will open the file, perform the operation, save it, then quit.

Can you give us an example of the file, so that we can investigate further?

Comment: sorry for the delay of my answer. The file was produced on Windows 7, thus I assume it is in the DOS format. I'm not even sure the program runs on Mac. By the way, the program is called [MapQTL](http://www.kyazma.nl/index.php/mc.MapQTL/). Anyway, my problem is now solved, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know your problem has been solved, and accepting my solution as the answer.

Comment: hi, what does " %s/\r/\r/g" do ? it looks like sed expression . replace '\r' with "\r"?

Comment: yup, that's what it does. The `%` in front applies the expression to all lines in the file. Due to the line-ending-handling magic of VIM, this seemingly useless expression apprarently does something.

Answer (score 21):

I know you have gotten this resolved, but I wanted to add a note for reference, based on some testing I've done.

If less is showing ^M, then like Sybren I suspect it is a MAC style ending (\r), not DOS (\r\n). You can determine that easily using cat:

$ cat -e filename

- Unix endings (\n) show as **$**
- MAC endings (\r) show as **^M** (less shows these)
- DOS\Windows endings (\r\n) show as **^M$** (less does not appear to show these)

Use dos2unix to get rid of the DOS (^M$) endings

Use **mac2unix** to get rid of the MAC (^M) endings - dos2unix won't get rid of these.

I had a file where I had to use dos2unix and mac2unix to get rid of all the non-Unix endings.

Comment: thanks for this answer, I was stumped running dos2unix, didn't realise the file was using the old mac line endings somehow.

Comment: IMO, should be actually the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tr -d '\r' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Notepad++ feature:
Edit>EOL Conversions>Unix(LF).

Now export this file to the Unix machine using pscp.exe.

Let me know if that worked for you.