# empty line in sed regexp fails to find stuff

Tags: regex, sed

I have this block in a text file. In vi (switching on the visualization of the end-of-line characters with `:set list` as per [View line-endings in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/view-line-endings-in-a-text-file)) it reads

```
 SHARE_INFO_FOR: SHARE/u_MYGROUP/$
 USER/GROUP   SHARES  PRIORITY  STARTED  RESERVED  CPU_TIME  RUN_TIME   ADJUST$
 u_zc        10000    3333.333     0        0         0.0        0       0.000$
 $
 SHARE_INFO_FOR: SHARE/u_MYSECONDGROUP/$
```

If I try to isolate this with sed I would use a multiple lines regexp

```
 sed -rn '/SHARE\/u_MYGROUP\//{:a;N;/^$/{/.*/p;d};ba}'
```

sed does not identifies the ending line of the block.
whereas if I explicitly put the content of if next non-empty line it works.

```
 sed -rn '/SHARE\/u_MYGROUP\//{:a;N;/SHARE\/u_MYSECONDGROUP\//{/.*/p;d};ba}'
```

My problem is of course that in general I do not know what is the group name in the next line so I wanted to delimit the interesting block using the name as a beginning marker and the empty line as end of block marker.

Do you see why `^$` is not working as a delimiter for the regexp in sed?

Comment: Is the file a DOS format file with CRLF endings?  Try `:set` in `vim` and see whether it is `fileformat=dos` or `fileformat=unix`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '\#SHARE/u_MYGROUP/#,/^$/{
 p
 }' YourFile
```

if it only need to print the block starting from line having `SHARE/u_MYGROUP/` until next first empty line. It change the default separator (`/`) for pattern by (`#`) using a first escape char for this

Comment: This is actually much better! thanks a lot! I made it an inline command to put into a script by using `sed -n '\#SHARE/u_MYGROUP/#,/^$/{p;}' lastlog`  It's too bad that I do not have enough reputation to vote up this answer.

Comment: You could replace the `{ p }` with just `p`, avoiding multiple lines.  Even if you need multiple actions grouped within `{ }`, you can often put them on one line with semicolons in between (and on Mac OS X, you need a semicolon after the last command and before the `}`).

Answer (score 0):

All of the sed language constructs to do anything with multiple lines LITERALLY became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/SHARE\/u_MYGROUP/' file
SHARE_INFO_FOR: SHARE/u_MYGROUP/
USER/GROUP   SHARES  PRIORITY  STARTED  RESERVED  CPU_TIME  RUN_TIME   ADJUST
u_zc        10000    3333.333     0        0         0.0        0       0.000
```