# npm package.json bin won't work on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, command-line-interface, bin

I am trying to start my cli tool via the package.json `bin` property.

I have the following:

```
...
"name": "mycli",
"bin": "./bin/mycli",
...
```

When I open the cmd in the package path and type: "mycli" it says that the command is not recognized.

Should I run an npm command? or use the scripts property? am I trying to access the bin property incorrectly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to specify the name of your `cli` tool in the `bin` property, like:

```
"bin": {
  "mycli": "./bin/mycli" // or "/bin/mycli.js" if it's a .js file
}
```

Then, run `npm link`, from inside your project folder, to create a global symbolic link to the current folder.

Don't forget to add the `"preferGlobal": "true"` property just before the `bin` property in your `package.json` file, in order to warn users to install your module globally.

Comment: Doesn't `/bin/mycli` work the same as `./bin/mycli`? The look the same to me...

Answer (score 18):

Whenever I was trying to get my app to link, I kept running into problems on Windows where the generated scripts that would execute on path would try to run the `*.js` file using the default Windows executable (I don't know what that would be).  I'm not sure why.  I think it might be because it is a JavaScript file.  However, I compared the generated scripts to some of the other modules I had installed, and figured out that if I made the `bin` file referenced by the `package.json` act as though it were to be executed on a `*nix` machine, `npm` would automatically try and add the call to node.

For example:

If my `package.json` looks like this:

## myapp/package.json

```
"name": "myapp",
"bin": {
    "myapp": "./bin/myapp"
}
```

My referenced bin file looks like this:

## myapp/bin/myapp

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require("../server.js");
```

The 2 generated executable files that appear in `%APPDATA%\npm` show up as follows by running the command `npm link` from within the `myapp` directory (which would have `package.json` in the root):

## myapp

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/myapp/bin/myapp" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/myapp/bin/myapp" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

## myapp.cmd

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\myapp\bin\myapp" %*
) ELSE (
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\myapp\bin\myapp" %*
)
```

Bear in mind, I didn't need to make the 2 files above explicitly, I just needed to have the file to be executed as the `bin` file in the `package.json`. `npm` did the file creation.

---

### Line Endings

One other thing to note that I ran into while using this method, make absolutely sure that your line endings are correct.  I noticed that my bin was erroring with: ": No such file or directory" whenever I installed on *nix machines because there was an incorrect line ending.  Thanks to [View line-endings in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376951/691711) for example of how to print visible line endings.

For example, if you run `cat -e PATH_TO_BIN` and get something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node^M$
^M$
require("../index.js");^M$
```

You're using the wrong line endings.  If you get something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node$
$
require("../index.js");$
```

Those should be the right line endings.

Comment: The "#!/usr/bin/env node" solved my issue the bin js scripts not being executed by node. THX

Answer (score 6):

If you put

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

in the first line of your script, npm will create the necessary wrapper scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Rodrigo Medeiros works for me, but only if I have too the shebang line at the .js file.

There I had another issue. I have node.js installed at c:\Program files\nodejs, and this was my shebang line:

```
#!c:/program files/nodejs/node
```

This didn't work, because the blank space. This was the correct one:

```
#!c:/progra~1/nodejs/node
```

Comment: that'll break non-windows support though. if you use `#!/usr/bin/env node` instead (as recommended in [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bin)), npm will detect that and generate the appropriate command on windows, and it'll also continue to work on macos and linux.