# Install a locally developed npm package globally

Tags: node.js, package, npm

I'm developing a node package that needs to be run from shell. I know I have to install the package globally, but running

```
$> npm install -g ./my_module
```

Does not give me the desired result, that is running

```
$> my_module
```

Results in

```
my_module: : command not found
```

Instead of running the entry point (`index.js`) of my node package.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious in here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add your package.json?

Comment: `npm list -g` gives the path where globally installed modules reside. ([checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages/5926706#5926706)) Try putting (link) your package there.

Comment: I have tried it and to no avail. I think I'll just publish the package to npm and call it a day

Comment: Ok, I was missing "bin" attribute in package.json. I've set it up and my problem is solved

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333570/npm-package-json-bin-wont-work-on-windows

Answer (score 63, accepted):

After setting up the right `package.json` configuration, (mainly using `{"bin": {...}}`), You don't have to publish it to NPM registry then download it again to see it working.

`npm link` made exactly for this situations. as described in the [offical documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link):

> `npm link` in a package folder will create a symlink in the global folder {prefix}/lib/node_modules/ that links to the package where the npm link command was executed.

Assuming you have this project:

```
-- my_module

-- -- index.js
-- -- cli.js
-- -- package.json
```

and you have this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my_module",
  "bin": {
    "my_module": "cli.js"
  },
}
```

Run:

```
cd my_module
```

Then:

```
npm link
```

Now npm will install your package globally in your machine. it will check the `package.json` for the `bin` entry, and it will link `my_module` to the `cli.js` file. This will happen by creating a symlink in the global npm directory to your current directory.

now if you run in your command line:

```
my_module
```

it will point to the `cli.js` file. if you changed `cli.js` contents, it will be reflected the next time you run `my_module`, if you renamed `my_module` to `my_module2`, use `npm unlink` then `npm link` again.

---

On a different note, npm can use a full url as a package name, it will use the full url to download and install the package instead of looking at the npm registry, you can install packages from your own private Git hosts, for example:

```
npm install -g https://github.com/Me/my_module
```

Comment: Hello Mohannad, is it valid to use:
npm install -g .
??

Comment: prefereGlobal is now depracted ([https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#preferglobal])

Comment: npm link worked for me. that and having the bin in the package json. took me awhile to finally get the correct google search keywords to get here. Thank you for this knowledge.

Comment: I've had issues with npm link using ng-packagr for library development (Angular 12 tbe). I thought it may be related to me using nvm-windows, but after removing it and installing node "normally" the issue persists.
So I guess for library development with ng-packagr we are limited to using "npm pack" and installing from archive :/
I hope someone corrects me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MohannadNaj, Thank you very much! `npm link` option worked perfectly for my case

Comment: for some reason this does not work for me. I followed your instructions and with `npm ls -g` it even shows up with `+-- my_module@0.0.2 -> .\E:\work\my_module` but when I run my JS with `node my_script.js`, that requires "my_module", I still get "Error: Cannot find module 'my_module'". What can be the reason for this? I found a post where it turned out the "main" entry in the modules's package.json was pointing to a non-existing file, but this is not the case here; the main file exists and is correct.

Answer (score 62):

Please try to pack the module and install.

```
npm pack
```

and then install it globally

```
npm i -g my_module-0.0.1.tgz
```

Let me know is this worked or not

Comment: `npm link` is useful when you want to debug, while developing. But once its been fully tested I think this solution is appropriate.

Comment: I wanted a multi stage docker build and this was the proper answer!
Build during the first stage and then produce a container with the package installed globally without issues with module dependencies. Just copy the `.tgz` between the two stages

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue recently. I developed my module as a CLI with the intent to be able to invoke it from anywhere, published it to the NPM registry and installed it using the `-g` option but when calling it from the command  line I was still getting the `command not found` error. Adding the `bin` attribute to the `package.json` file is what did the trick.

From the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin):

> A lot of packages have one or more executable files that they’d like to install into the PATH. npm makes this pretty easy (in fact, it uses this feature to install the “npm” executable.)
>
> To use this, supply a `bin` field in your package.json which is a map of command name to local file name. On install, npm will symlink that file into `prefix/bin` for global installs, or `./node_modules/.bin/` for local installs.

Meaning your `package.json` file should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo-cli",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A CLI to do Foo-ish things.",
    "bin": {
        "foo": "./cli.js"
    },
    "main": "main.js",
    ...
}
```

The property can be a single string if you only wish to specify one single command, or a map if you wish to specify many. Now you should be able to call `foo` from anywhere in the command line.