# How do I globally install a Node.js command-line script on the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, command-line-interface, npm-install

As a prototype, I’ve written a simple **Node.js** command-line script which loads a **.txt** file and outputs the contents. I’ve read many articles which suggest that Node.js scripts are usually executed **via the command-line and should be installed globally**, so that’s the direction I’ve taken, even if there are other techniques.

For the sake of this query, my globally installed command is called `my-prototype`.

This all works fine on the desktop but I intend to host this prototype on a server, using Express.

How do I **globally install** `my-prototype` **on the server** and, if that’s possible, will I be able to execute it in the same way as in my local tests, as a child process?:

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process')
const output = execSync(`${process.execPath} my-prototype`)
console.log(output.toString())
```

I'm not entirely sure that globally installing command-line scripts is for use on a server and wonder whether that's for desktop use only.

Comment: Why do you want to host that on an express server? Like what exactly do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: From what I think I understand from your question, you are looking into creating a node package.

Comment: You can check “how to create a npm package with node” on Google.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440893/install-a-locally-developed-npm-package-globally huh?

Comment: Hi @EAzevedo, thanks for replying. With regards to using Express, let’s just say that I wish to host it on a ‘server’ (whatever that may be), so that it’s available as a service for me to use while on the move. If not Express, what would you alternatively suggest? I’m familiar with creating Node packages but I’m not familiar with installing them globally on a server. I’m questioning how to do this and whether, if I achieve this, my example code above would function correctly, as it currently does on my desktop.

Comment: Hi @Vadim, thank you for the link. While perfectly explaining how to globally install a module, this doesn't help me in my quest to do so on a server, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve, you described the solution you are looking for, not the problem 

Comment: So you want to make it available online so you can install it? Like store it somewhere and install it whenever you need?

Comment: Hi @Vadim, I'm trying to stick to what I've learnt is best, that being the use of **global command-line** for Node.js. However, I'm concerned that this may be for desktop use only as I haven't yet found a way to use this strategy on a _server_. I'm looking to call a web-service/function (if that's the best terminology), which reads files from the server, by way of command-line Node.js, and then return that content after various manipulation (beyond my current simple prototype). **What you've provided in your own post below is getting closer to describing what I'm struggling to convey.**

Comment: Hi @EAzevedo, no, that's not what I'm trying to do but thank you for highlighting how my original query has not been clear enough. Let me explain... If you can picture, during development on your desktop, we run `npm i`, which installs all of our package dependencies. I want to do the same thing but on the server, so that my server-side code can use the installed modules. Only, in my case, I'm looking to install my module globally and target it directly, using `node my-prototype`, rather than `require('my-prototype')`.

Comment: So you want, in your server command line, run node my-prototype? Or where do you want to run that command? If you want to use your my-prototype module in your express server code, you will need to require it or import it.

Comment: what might also be possible, is that you manually install the script globally on your server (but you will need access to do it), then you can create a wrapper class in your express server to spawn a process that uses that global command.

Comment: Hi @EAzevedo, so unless I have access to the server, there is no way for me to install **global** modules. Is this the same for `npm install`ing **non-global** module dependencies, listed in `package.json`? I hope not, as that would stop me creating any of my own modules at all, even for requiring/importing them. It would also stop me using any third-party modules (unless they're built-in; e.g. `fs`, `path`, `process`, etc.)

Comment: I believe you could achieve that by deploying a node script that installs your package globally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237978/discussion-between-eazevedo-and-moo).

Answer (score 0):

If you need just *output the contents*, then you do not need a console, or rather: you only need it once, to run nodejs

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//

app.get('/', async(req, res)=>{
    let fileContains = fs.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf8');
    try{
        fileContains = JSON.parse(fileContains);
    }catch(e){}
    res.json(fileContains);
});

//

app.listen(80);
```

Also, read a little more about the [pm2 module](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/), it's very useful

Comment: Hi Vadim, although this isn’t exactly what I was looking for, it’s **extremely** helpful in describing what I’d like to achieve - thank you! Rather than calling `fs.readFileSync()`, I’d like to call my own **global command**; e.g. `let fileContains = execSync('node my-prototype')`, as I expect `my-prototype` to do a lot more than just read a file later on.

Comment: Hi Vadim, please also see my message to EAzevedo on the OP, which better explains how I wish to install and use my module. Vadim's comment highlighted where my OP may have confused. I'm apologise, I'm very confused myself and quite new to some of Node.js' implementation.