# Official Jenkins Dockerfile acting strange

Tags: jenkins, docker

I want to use the official jenkins docker image from here :
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/tree/62de121e41ddd92ef34e9999162932334b05f0d7
and further customize it.

When i just launch a container with `docker run -d -p 8080 jenkins` , it plays ok.
But when I download all the project and build it locally [as it is,without changing anything], when I launch a container it exits right after launch.

Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: more detail log required to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

are you're using Docker Toolbox on Windows?

If yes, [be carreful with end of line different between Windows and Linux](http://w3blog.fr/en/2016/02/19/docker-toolbox-and-git-on-windows/).

Try to clone repository like this

```
git clone myrepo --config core.autocrlf=false
```

Comment: I am using Docker inside an AWS instance with Amazon Linux. I copy paste the dockerfile in a windows environment and pull it using git to build it on the instance.

Comment: Do you have the exact message? check your file with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/view-line-endings-in-a-text-file

Comment: For me, end of line was changed in plugins.txt file.