# Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT script doesn't run when the container starts if docker compose is ran from Gitlab pipelines

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

My container has a shell script that runs after the container starts. It was working before but when I push it to Gitlab and ran it with a pipeline it doesn't start. Here's my Dockerfile.

**Dockerfile**

```
# Setup SQL Server 2019
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Banana100
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer

USER mssql

#Copy test database and create DB script to image working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 1433

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

What's weird is that whenever I delete the `/bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh`, retype it, then run `docker compose --force-recreate --build -d` on my local machine, the shell script is executed just fine. But if the pipeline do it, it doesn't work. I have nothing to push on my repo, Git thinks I didn't make any changes at all.

[This post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905135/why-wont-my-docker-entrypoint-sh-execute) suggest that it could be an issue with the line endings. It probably worked on most people but I have tried these with no luck:

[Daniel Howard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40537078/8331324)

[P.J.Meisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38905412/8331324)

[Ryan Allen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143688/8331324)

My `entrypoint.sh` is a shell script that runs an SQL file to create and restore database. Please see the codes below.

**entrypoint.sh**

```
# /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P FBuilder*09 -d master -i createDB.sql
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i createDB.sql

while true; do sleep 1000; done
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  fb_db:
    container_name: test_fbdb
    build: ./test.environment
    ports:
      - "5002:1433"
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
.ci_server:
  tags:
    - ci

stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  SOLUTION_NAME: FBSVC.sln

before_script:
 - Set-Variable -Name "time" -Value (date -Format "%H:%m")
 - echo ${time}
 - echo "started by ${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"

build:
  stage: build
  extends:
    - .ci_server
  script:
    - echo "Restoring project dependencies..."
    - $Env:Path += ";C:\nuget"
    - nuget restore
    - echo "Preparing development environment"
    - copy "D:\CI_TestDB\FormulaBuilder\FormulaBuilder.bak" "D:\Project Files\Gitlab-Runner\builds\_1ZgTgcF\0\water-utilities\formula-builder\test.environment"
    - docker compose up --force-recreate --build -d
    - echo "Publishing project..."
    - $Env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
    - msbuild FBSVC.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=CI_IntegrationTest
    - echo "Build stage completed successfully!"
  only:
    - merge_requests

test:
    stage: test
    variables:
      GIT_STRATEGY: clone
    extends: 
      - .ci_server
    script:
        - echo "Installing dev dependencies..."
        - npm ci
        - echo "Running tests..."
        - npm run cy:test
    dependencies:
        - build
    only:
        - merge_requests
```

The Gitlab Runner is running on my physical local machine, it is not a Shared Runner. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

#### UPDATE (June 24, 2022)

I have replaced the ENTRYPOINT on the Dockerfile to `ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]`, it is still do the same issue. Looking at the "**Select End Line Sequence**" menu on VS Code found at the bottom-right corner, it is set to "**LF**". I checked the Dockerfile being pulled by the pipeline it is now set to "**CRLF**". Does this matter?

I have ran `git config --global core.autocrlf input` multiple times but if the file is being pulled from the repo, it automatically does this. Hence, I decided to detach the folder containing my files that builds my database environment for the time being. Doing this requires rewriting the whole `ENTRYPOINT` line on my Dockerfile to work properly again. If you have any advice, please let me know.

Comment: Any `core.autocrlf` setting you set in your local repository is *local*. GitLab will be using *their* repository, which has its own `core.autocrlf` (which is always turned off, you cannot and would not want to turn it on). Dockerfiles should be *committed* with LF-only endings, because Docker is a Linux-y system. Your scripts should also be committed with LF-only line endings. It's probably wise to store and edit them as LF-only, but if you must edit on a Windows system, having Git translate *from* CRLF *to* LF-only is an option.

Comment: If you can use everything as LF-only, consider using `dos2unix` or similar tools to make sure *all* shell scripts are LF-only now and forever.

Comment: Maybe try adding some debug output to your script and running `docker compose` without the `-d` flag to see the logging output.