# docker exec /home/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, shell

Im try up a Stack, but when i deploy a container using `docker compose up`, the postgresQL up, but my app in Python send this exception.

[Error in pythonapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAOWh.png)

But the *entrypoint.sh* still in container.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCQu8.png)

This is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:alpine3.18
    container_name: postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=paulitos
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_DB=eventon
  pythonapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: pythonapi
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.18

VOLUME /home/app/data

WORKDIR /home

COPY app /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/home/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\033[0;32m Instalando dependencias \033[0;32m"

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install -r requirements.txt

echo -e "\033[0;32m Iniciando aplicacao \033[0;32m"

echo -e "\033[1;33m Iniciando Migração "  $IP "\033[1;33m"

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

echo -e "\033[1;33m Iniciando Serviço "  $IP "\033[1;33m"

python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38905135/596285

Comment: Why does your output say `RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh` is step 5/5 while it is 6/8?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```

Your script wants to start bash. There is no bash installed in docker alpine image. Install bash or change the script to sh.

Comment: I changed it, but it's not changing the error

Answer (score 0):

The `WORKDIR` is already `/home/app`. Try changing the `CMD` to just `entrypoint.sh`