# Docker php container not starting (Bash problem)

Tags: bash, docker

I´m completly new to docker, and I just got a project under a docker container which I can´t make it start (It´s stucked restarting the container).

The issue is with one of the containers in this repo, is a php server that is giving me the following error:

```
': No such file or directory't execute 'bash
```

I have researched the web for a solution, and this is what i have found so far:

-The image is based in alpine 3.16 system, which has no bash interpreter

-I´ve tried to add bash to the Dockerfile like this

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

And it seems it´s not working (it might be im not adding it to the right file, but I think i did, the file was Dockerfile under /docker/php/ dir)

Im not sure of which files i need to share for giving more info about the problem but im open to any request. Thanks for your time

Comment: That error message looks like what you might get if a script has DOS-style line endings but runs in a Linux container.  That is one of the possible causes of [Why won't my docker-entrypoint.sh execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905135/why-wont-my-docker-entrypoint-sh-execute)