# Dired appears with 015 (Octal?)

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, dired, end-of-line

Recently, my `Dired` listing in Emacs starting appearing with `015` at the end of each line:

[image: Screenshot of 015]

I'm not sure what brought it on.  I had been making some changes with my Spacemacs layers but since then I've gone to a completely out-of-the-box Spacemacs configuration and the `015`s are still there.  It makes `Dired` pretty much useless because if I try to select a file or drill into a directory it doesn't recognize it.  Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are **Control M** characters. Emacs writes them as either `^M` (one char, not two) or `\015` (again, one char, not 4).

This Emacs Wiki page tells you about this: [EndOfLineTips](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EndOfLineTips).

This is some of what it says:

> If you see `^M` in your file, you may have opened a file with DOS-style line endings (carriage return + line feed) while Emacs assumes it has Unix-style line endings (line feed only). (The carriage-return character, sometimes abbreviated as `CR`, is `^M`. The line-feed character, sometimes abbreviated as `LF`, is `^J`.)
>
> You can reopen the file with the correct line ending with a command like `C-x C-m r dos`.

`C-x C-m r` is bound to `revert-buffer-with-coding-system`.  Use `C-h k` or `C-h f` to see more about it.

See also (`C-h v`) variable `buffer-file-coding-system`.

Also: use `i line endings` in the Emacs manual, to go to node [Coding Systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Coding-Systems.html). That tells all you need to know about this.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3569997/729907) and its answers might also help.  And see the UNIX/Linux command `dos2unix`.

Comment: I've seen the  ^M but didn't realize \015 was the same animal!  It was also strange seeing them in the Dired rather than in a file that I'd opened.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Right. I had to look up \015 octal, myself. ;-)