# How to ignore alternate lineterminator in pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file having lot of rows with 6 columns in each row but there is a \n after every fourth column as well as every 6th column, something like:

Row 1 ---> 1 2 3 4\n
5 6\n

Row 2 ---> 7 8 9 10\n
11 12\n

I am using the command to create dataframe from the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('info.txt', header=None, delimiter=r"\s+", names = cols, lineterminator='\n')
```

But, pandas read_csv is reading the above data as 4 rows even if I am explicitly providing the names of the 6 columns in names attribute of read_csv:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0   1    2   3    4    NaN  NaN
1   5    6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   7    8   9    10   NaN  NaN
3   11   12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

How can I read the data as :

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0   1    2   3    4    5    6
1   7    8   9    10   11   12
```

Comment: What is your line terminator in the file? I mean the symbol at the end of  `1 2 3 4\n 5 6\n` ? Do you have a windows/mac line-ending (`\r`, `\r\n`)?

Comment: I did a open('info.txt','r+b').read() on the text file and I can see the numerical data and the \n characters written in the pattern e.g.: 61  4  2  242\n  392  4\n , so the line terminator should be \n but it's appearing twice in a row hence creating the problem. There is no other distinguishing symbol after the second \n and new row values start after the second \n in the same pattern.

Comment: You probably has a non-unix line endings (not a `\n`). Otherwise you would get `61 4 2 242` and `392 4` as a separate lines. You can try to find your line endings using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/how-to-find-out-line-endings-in-a-text-file

Comment: I ran `file info.txt` and its giving the response `info.txt: ASCII text` and when I view the file, its showing `61 4 2 242` and `392 4` as separate lines. So looks like \n is only line-separator but its not aligned to the data.

Comment: Are you using macos? It's sounds impossible to me to have a single line `1 2 3 4\n 5 6\n` and your editor display it as a separate lines and open() show it as a separate lines. You can do the following: inspect the newlines in a binary viewer, for example `cat info.txt | od -c | less`. I believe that you have a macos line-endings (\r) and you can try `pd.read_csv(..., lineterminator='\r')`

Comment: Yes, I am using Macos and after running `cat info.txt | od -c | less` I am still not seeing any other line delimiters except \n.  Thanks @AlexanderVolkovsky for the tips on checking for line terminators!

Comment: So you need to read two lines as a single line. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file-like object with custom reading logic. file-like object must contain an `__iter__` and `read` methods.

Test data:
`echo -en '1 2 3 4\n 5 6\n 7 8 9 10\n 11 12\n' > info.txt`

```py
class MultiLineReader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.fd = None

    # use as context manager in order to open and close file correctly
    def __enter__(self):
        self.fd = open(self.filename, 'r')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.fd.close()

    # file-like object must have this method
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            line = self.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            yield line

    # file-like object must have this method
    # just read a line 
    def read(self, size=-1):
        return self.readline()

    # read two lines at a time
    def readline(self):
        return self.fd.readline().strip() + self.fd.readline()

# example usage
with MultiLineReader("info.txt") as f:
    pd.read_csv(f, sep=r'\s+', header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from the answer by @gold_cy, was able to solve the problem by extending the last element of the list for each alternate row instead of appending a new row to the list:

```
def strip_newlines(fp):
    file_data_without_line_breaks = []
    i=-1
    with open(fp, "r") as fin:
        for val, line in enumerate(fin.readlines()):
            stripped_line = line.rstrip()
            if(val%2 == 1):
              file_data_without_line_breaks[i].extend(stripped_line.split())
            else:
              i=i+1
              file_data_without_line_breaks.append(stripped_line.split())
    return file_data_without_line_breaks
```

But this may not be appropriate for large data as the list object is being created in-memory.

Comment: You will also get your numbers as strings with this approach.

Comment: Yes, but I am still able create the dataframe as intended by using `listVal = strip_newlines("info.txt")        
df = pd.DataFrame(listVal, columns=cols)`