# Trying to delete a bunch of files listed in a specific file using a git bash loop

Tags: windows, git, shell, command-line, git-bash

how are you doing? Let me explain what is happening to me:
I've created a UE5 project and there are some huge files, I'm trying to remove them from the git directory
using the command `git rm --cached`. When I try to delete a single file, `using git rm --cached example/path/path`,  it works very well, like the image-0 shows:
[image-0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOHC5.png)

But when I put all paths in a single file, and try to use a while loop to delete them one by one, it doesn't work! I tried to use the command:
`while read line; do git rm --cached "$line"; done < filestoremove.txt`
and I got the error:
`error fatal: pathspec 'example/path/file.example?' did not match any files`
Like the image-1 shows:
[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClpZv.png)

I've checked if the file had any special characters using Notepad++ and certified that the file is UTF-8. How u can see, the **filestoremove.txt** is in the same directory that *Content/* folder is, take a look at image-2:
[image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Giql.png)

An example of content in the file, image-3:
[image-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjLZT.png)

As you can imagine it isn't possible to remove each one using git rm to each file without a loop command.

I want to delete all archives listed in the **filestoremove.txt** using a single command.

Comment: _"I'm trying to remove them from the git directory using the command git rm --cached"_ are you aware that `git rm --cached` only removes files from the index, not from the working tree?

Comment: Yeah, I need those files to stay in the working directory, just remove them from the staging area, but I don't understand how this question could help me.

Comment: Please use code blocks for text (copy paste), not images. And if the images show non-textual content then please inline them.

Comment: check your textfile does not have DOS line endings. The `?` is almost certainly git's representation of `\r` / `^M` / ASCII 13. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3569997/10971581

Comment: Run your command with `set -v` and `set -x` turned on, so that you can see better what is actually being executed.

Comment: It works jhnc, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, specially to user [jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971581/jhnc), his solution works for me, just do it:

```
dos2unix file.txt
```

Then run the loop in git bash:

```
while read line; do git rm --cached "$line"; done < files.txt
```