# Unexpected Error "file name too long" and bad output of `head -1` ending in ^M

Tags: shell, zsh, head

I’m currently working on a zsh script on my Mac to automate a process. The script involves reading the first line of a .txt file from a distant directory and passing it to another function.

Here’s the function I’ve written:

```
function f1() {
  # Read the first line of the file
  local line1="$(head -n 1 "$1" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '^M')"

  # Compute the values using a different function
  local value1=$(f2 "$line1")

  echo "$value1"
}
```

However, when I call this function with a directory path that is a very long string (e.g., `Folder1/folder2/folder3/...`), I encounter an error and the output is incorrect.

When I test `line1=$(head -n 1 "$dir" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '^M')`,  I get the following error:

```
$line1

zsh: file name too long: First line of file.^M
```

Here, `First line of file.` is the first line of the file that I want to read. I’ve tried removing trailing new lines with `tr -d '^M'` and `tr -d '\n'`, but neither approach seems to help.
Also, the error is not there when the directory name is short, and the functions are evaluated correctly.

I’m at a loss as to why this is happening. It seems like a very peculiar bug, and I haven’t been able to find much information on it. Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the line endings of your input text file (some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3570574)). You may be getting the entire input file as the file name.

Comment: I'm very confused about where the error is coming from. Does `f2` try to use its argument as a filename, and the error is coming from inside that? In any case, "^M" is probably a printable representation of the carriage return character (aka Control-M), so `tr -d '\r'` would remove it. See ["Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525)
and ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571)

Comment: @GordonDavisson That did the job!. carriage return, I didn't know what it was called. I can accept this as an answer if you wish to write it as such. But I'm still baffled by why this is happening. Why is there no carriage return when the file has a short file name?

Comment: @Gairfowl Indeed, it was the line endings of the input text file. The file is recognised as `ASCII text, with very long lines (702), with CRLF line terminators`, while a regular .txt file as only `ASCII text`. Thanks ! So it didn't have to do anything with the file name being long. Interestingly, only the first line had a carriage return character, and the second one didn't (although the second line was the last line of the file). And the reason why the short file name worked is because I copy-pasted the text as opposed to the file.

Comment: Glad your solved your problem, but this issue has been asked and answered 100s of times already. See the section [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) in the bash/info page.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Fine with me. When searching I concentrated on `file name too long` because I thought that was the issue, and I couldn't replicate the error on a short file name file due to a mistake that I made.

Comment: Regarding "I’m currently working on a bash (zsh) script" - bash and zsh are 2 different shells so that's like saying "I'm traveling in my car (boat)". From the error message you shared it looks like you're actually using zsh, right?

Comment: Are you working on a bash script, or on a zsh script? Are you travelling to arctica or to antarctica? You can't do both at the same time.